# nginx, redirection http to https not working as expected

Tags: nginx, ssl, redirect

My intention is to redirect all requests to `https://` prefixed URLs for both the naked domain and for the `www.*` equivalent. The `acme-challenge` URL is to be excluded.

I've tried with the below config, and get correctly redirected from the naked domain, but when I visit the `www.` prefixed one, I am presented with the default server, not redirected to server on port 443 and served from the https server root.

Why is this?

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name example.org www.example.org;

        location '/.well-known/acme-challenge/' {
                root /var/www/challenges;
        }

        location / {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;

        server_name example.org www.example.org;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/example.org.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.org.key;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:50m;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparams.pem;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        root /var/www/example.org/;
}
```

Comment: Please enable debug log and show the output of a request which isn't working as expected.

Comment: Try adding `ssl on;` to the https server block.